# Parse error when programmatically downloading and starting an app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and have been trying to let my app auto-update. This is a private app that doesn't go through the Store, only the `.apk` is manipulated.

I'm downloading the `.apk` and starting it programmatically when a newer version is available. The download seems to be going fine, but when launching the downloaded `.apk`, I get a parse error.

```
        try
        {          
            this.OnEnded += Download_OnEnded;

            string uri = string.Format("setupFilesAndroid/{0}/{1}", this.distantVersion, App.CommonDatas.ANDROID_INSTALLER_NAME);

            //Prepare the client for the download
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(this.baseUri)
            };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Computer-id", CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id);

            //Create or get the right folder and file to download to
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder appFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("App", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            IFile file = await appFolder.CreateFileAsync("app.apk", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            //Download the file
            using (var fileHandler = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
            {
                var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                byte[] dataBuffer = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                await fileHandler.WriteAsync(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
            }

            if (this.OnEnded != null)
            {
                this.OnEnded(this, null);
            }
        }
        catch {}
```

And the method called with the `OnEnded` event:

```
    //throws an error if the file doesn't exists
    //this works fine so I guess the file is in fact downloaded
        try
        {
            IFolder folder = await FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.GetFolderAsync("App");
            IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("app.apk");
        }
        catch
        {}

        //Use of Dependency service for launching the downloaded app
        IDownloadManager native = DependencyService.Get<IUpdateManager>();
        native.RunUpdate();
```

And this is the `RunUpdate()` method:

```
        IFolder folder = await FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.GetFolderAsync("App");
        IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("app.apk");

        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(file.Path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        Forms.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);
```

Any help? Or at least a pointer on how to debug this?

Edit: The update works fine when downloading and installing it manually. I can't find a way to check the programmatically downloaded file though as it's downloaded into an inaccessible path (something like `/data/user/0/...`).

Edit2: After some more tests, the downloaded file is fine and is able to fully reinstall the app, so the error most likely happens on `Forms.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);`

Comment: Does the updated APK you're downloading install when you install is manually? Did you check that the file isn't corrupt or signed wrongly etc?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say it but yes, everything goes fine when I download and update manually. Though I can't have access to the downloaded file when I do this programmatically so I can't check that.

Comment: Why not to store the file there where you've permission to do I/O ? @yurden

Comment: I had the same issue and it were network related problems. Calculate MD5 hash of the APK to be sure that it is "downloaded successfully".

Comment: @Toaster Well the user shouldn't ever see that downloaded file anywhere, it should all happen "magically" to him. Besides, I'm still unsure of my knowledge regarding storage on mobile, and PCLStorage offers either LocalStorage or RoamingStorage so I stuck with LocalStorage which was the one used in almost every threads I've read on the matter.

Comment: @EvZ What do you mean? Should I compare the MD5 hash of the APK on the server and the one I downloaded programmatically to check if they are exactly the same? Can I do this through my code or do I have to use an app for that?

Comment: One minute please. How did you know that `path` **is inaccessible** ??

Comment: Look, when your app's code can write there, then it will be able to do all file ops there

Comment: @Toaster I can't find the folder that should be created to contain the file, but my code above still tells me the file exists where it should be after the download ended. I read on another SO thread that those paths that look like this (`/data/user/0/...`) aren't meant to be accessed, even by the file manager, that's why I can't find the folder manually.

Comment: Yes, I understand. By, natively in Android, each system files created by any app will be accessible by his lord (parent)...

Filemanager is another app, another context, don't mix up your concept.

Comment: @Toaster that's what I understood, even though I struggled to express it clearly :). But as I can't access the file myself, I can't debug the parse error or even check if the whole file has been downloaded without being corrupted or anything.

Comment: Let's continue to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173979/discussion-between-yurden-and-toaster).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I implement an AutoUpdater for our app.
In my case the source of the problem was that I simply forgot to flush the filestream which was writing the file after it was done.